# Md-button in side nav is offset when it is below a certain width

Tags: angular-material

I am using materials Md-button's in a md-side-nav and this button is offset when it it 4 characters long. I inspected the css of these two button and the only thing that is different is the origin transform

Codepen: click toggle right nav to see the effect.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXpdae

```
<md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
      123456
    </md-button><br>

    <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
      123456789
    </md-button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add this to the menu, as when wrapping the button with an  the text is centered

a {
    text-align: left;
  }